# Add multiple users to People or Group field of a list using PowerShell

Tags: 2010, 2013, powershell

I would like to add some users to a people or groups field of a custom list with PowerShell? How can I do that?

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/sp2010-update-a-multi-user-field-person-or-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection]$lotsofpeople = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection            
$user1 = $w.EnsureUser("domain\user1");            
$user1Value = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($w, $user1.Id, $user1.LoginName)            
$user2 = $w.EnsureUser("domain\user2");            
$user2Value = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($w, $user2.Id, $user2.LoginName);            
$lotsofpeople.Add($user1Value);            
$lotsofpeople.Add($user2Value);            
$i["lotsofpeoplefield"] = $lotsofpeople;            
$i.Update();            
#-or-            
$l.Fields["lotsofpeoplefield"].ParseAndSetValue($i,$lotsofpeople);            
$i.Update();
```

Where `$i` is the list item to update. `$w` is the `SPWeb` object.

Reference - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx#Set_and_Get_a_Multi-Person_Field